# Discord.py commands.CommandInvokeError not triggering: discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My bot is currently only allowed and has permissions to send and manage messages in one channel. If I trigger a command like `$enable` in the permitted channel, the enable command will check if the user has admin rights or not. If it doesn't, it triggers the `MissingPermissions` error down below and messages the channel with error.

I am now trying to trigger another command `$help` in a channel that the bot has no permission in and this results in this error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_command_error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\User\Documents\discordbots\bot1\bot.py", line 212, in on_command_error
    await ctx.message.delete()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\message.py", line 1022, in delete
    await self._state.http.delete_message(self.channel.id, self.id)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

As it should, since the command is being used in a channel that the bot is not allowed to mingle in. Ideally I would like to catch it and print to console something simple rather than a full error.

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(description="Commands", color=config.main_color)
    embed.add_field(value="Check bot status", name="`$status`", inline=False)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    await ctx.message.delete()

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        print("Command used in invalid channel")
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send(error, delete_after=30)
        return
```

I tried catching it with the `commands.CommandInvokeError` but it doesn't even seem to be printing to the console and it's still displaying the full error. I also tried an alternative method below which seems to have the same result, in that it doesn't even go into the print statement.

```
@help.error
async def help_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandInvokeError):
        print("hey")
        return
```

Comment: Problem is that your bot doesnt have permission to delete a message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the try/except syntax:

```py
try:
    this_might_go_wrong()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Oops... The error was: {e}")
```